# How to pass form data to external php script

Tags: php, url, forms

I need to pass a value from a form to an external php script via a url, but my code isn't working. When I submit my form, I'm expecting the url to look like this: example.com/script.php?zip=12345 but what I'm getting is this: example.com/script.php? with nothing after the ?.
My form code is below. Am I doing something wrong, or do I need to change a setting somewhere?

```
        <form id="map" method="get" action="script.php">
            <input type="text" class="inline" id="zip" />
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Go" />
        </form>
```

Comment: I would say that this is not an ExpressionEngine-related question and is better server by StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `name` attribute on the text field.

```
<input type="text" class="inline" id="zip" name="zip" />
```

You may just want to change `id` to `name` (that would depend on whether or not you're using the ID for any CSS/jQuery selectors).

Comment: Doh! I must have looked at that code 100 times and not noticed that there was no `name`. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. For future reference Derek is right though. Any non-EE questions would be better off posted on Stack Overflow.